# What is the difference between "filesystem readahead" and "readahead"?

Tags: linux, block-device

From [`man 8 blockdev`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/util-linux/blockdev.8.en.html):

> The utility `blockdev` allows one to call block device ioctls from the command line.

My question is about the following options:

> `--getfra`
> Get filesystem readahead in 512-byte sectors.
>
> `--getra`
> Print readahead (in 512-byte sectors).
>
> `--setfra sectors`
> Set filesystem readahead (same as `--setra` on 2.6 kernels).
>
> `--setra sectors`
> Set readahead (in 512-byte sectors).

I think I know what readahead is in general. What confuses me is "filesystem readahead".

1. Why are there two separate options: "filesystem readahead" and "readahead"? How do they differ?
2. Has "filesystem readahead" anything to do with filesystems? What? And *if so*, then what is the deal with letting `blockdev` manage this?

   <sup>I mean `blockdev` works with block devices (right?), block devices and filesystems are different levels of abstraction (right?) and we still value ["do one thing and do it well"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well) (*right?*). This is why `blockdev` dealing with "filesystem something" is surprising to me.</sup>

Comment: Note that a mounted filesystem must be on a blockdev.  So yes, blcokdev is a lower abstraction than filesystem, but when a real filesystem is mounted, there is a 1:1 bidirectional correspondence with some blockdev.

Comment: @user10489 tmpfs is a filesystem not on a block device (or am I missing something?). And right now I'm using Btrfs that uses *two* block devices; it's a "real filesystem" without "1:1 bidirectional correspondence".

Comment: tmpfs is not a "real" filesystem -- it is virtual, and has no block device, there's a lot of those.   Good point on btrfs, similarly zfs, probably others.  Relation is more complex there.  Note that blockdev won't work with those, and those probably also have their own settings for these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The two are there for historical reasons; they [have been equivalent](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6.6/source/block/ioctl.c#L544) for twenty years or so IIRC. I can’t remember what the distinction was.
2. `blockdev` does one thing (as mentioned in its man page, quoted in the question): it provides access to block device `ioctl`s. Get/set (file system) read-ahead are four block device `ioctl`s, which is why `blockdev` has switches for them.

Comment: (1) So they are equivalent. The manual could state this clearly. Frankly I interpreted "same as `--setra` on 2.6" as "`--setfra` currently is what `--setra` was on 2.6" and I suspected there was some change after 2.6 that caused renaming the old `--setra` to `--setfra` and introducing a new `--setra`. If I understand correctly, it was probably the other way around: two options converged, two names remained. (2) This shifts the question to "what is the deal with letting block device ioctls manage filesystems?". Irrelevant now, it seems the word "filesystem" here is just a misleading remnant.

Comment: They may be equivalent at the kernel level but still separate at the user level, so the tool wouldn't know.  But that doesn't prevent the documentation from mentioning that.  Problem is, a lot of the options in this tool would have documentation burred in kernel api docs or source code.

Comment: In practice the documentation here is (unfortunately) buried in changelogs — I haven’t taken the time yet to dig into that. As you say, Kamil, the different `ioctl`s had meaning some time ago, but the distinction became meaningless. Since `blockdev` is a very thin shim above the `ioctl`s, and the latter remain, the options remain. The documentation should indeed be updated (I’ll add that to my ever-growing todo list, but if anyone else wants to take care of it feel free!).